# Angular7 interpolating values inside a string on an img="" in the html markup throws "quotes are not supported for evaluation"

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular7

I'm making an internal app that displays vimeo videos in a grid, i'm binding the source of each iteration and trying to replace the video ID in the link template like this:

```
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ allVideos.title }}?color=25b86e&title=0&byline=0" 
      frameborder="0"
      webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
      </iframe>
```

The problem is, I'm getting an error saying "quotes are not supported for evaluation" which is weird as I've done this before in the past.

Comment: why not binding ? `<iframe [src]="getVideoLinkByTitle(video.title)"></iframe>`

Comment: can you show us an exemple of the allVideos.title value ?
else try to set the complete source url in a variable like Stavm said ↑

Comment: @Stavm thanks, I've ended up doing it like that but I also realized I was trying to put in there the wrong variable. Now evereything works. If you post your reply as an answer I'm happy to mark it as the right one, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not binding ?

`<iframe [src]="getVideoLinkByTitle(video.title)"></iframe>`

Comment: This is precisely what I ended up doing with the extra step of using the Dom Sanitizer as I was getting an error.